# More Weak Classifiers Yields Lower Accuracy in Sklearn Adaboost

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost

I'm doing a quick classification project on the MNIST dataset just to do some time trials and testing with various classifiers.

One of the classifiers I'm interested in is AdaBoost. I want to vary the `n_est` parameter which controls the number of weak estimators used in the algorithm.

When I increase the number of estimators from `n_est=100` to `n_est=200`, the test set accuracy actually decreases, which is not the behavior that I was expecting. Is there any reason that this would be happening? The testing set and training set is partitioned the same each time. The sets are disjoint and complete.

Here is my code:

```
# Documentation:
# AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=None, n_estimators=50, learning_rate=1.0, algorithm='SAMME.R', random_state=None)
# base_estimator - this is what the ensemble is built off of
# n_estimators - the max number of estimators at which boosting is terminated
#                if it's a perfect fit, then we stop early
classifier = skl_ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator = None, n_estimators = n_est)

# Make a header
print_pretty('AdaBoost Classifier Model')

# Train
print('Please wait. Training classifier...')
start = time.time()
score1 = classifier.fit(image_array, label_array).score(image_array, label_array)
end = time.time()
total_time = end - start

# Show results
print('\tClassifier has been trained in time: {0:.3f} seconds with n_est = {1}'.format(total_time, n_est))
print('\tClassifier training accuracy: {0:.3f}%'.format(score1*100))
```

The code is relatively simple to reproduce. I am 99% sure there's not a big in the code. I create two different classifiers and train them independently on the same source.

Does anyone know why this behavior would be logical? Here's an output from one of the runs:

```
========================================
         AdaBoost Classifier Model       
========================================
Please wait. The AdaBoost classifier is being trained...
Classifier has been trained in time: 214.000 seconds with n_est = 100
Classifier training accuracy: 73.237% (should be the same as: 73.237%)
Now predicting with test set...
Test set prediction time: 1.235 seconds
Test set accuracy: 72.960%
Average cross val score: 0.612%
========================================
       AdaBoost Classifier Model       
========================================
Please wait. The AdaBoost classifier is being trained...
Classifier has been trained in time: 505.418 seconds with n_est = 200
Classifier training accuracy: 72.188% (should be the same as: 72.188%)
Now predicting with test set...
Test set prediction time: 1.643 seconds
Test set accuracy: 72.060%
Average cross val score: 0.566%
```

Thank you!